# ReactJS Is passing objects via props or reading every time from database more performant

Tags: reactjs, performance, performance-testing

I have a ReactJS project and I am wondering what is more performant:

Assuming I have a index page and in it 3 components that each require data from a database to display and edit. I can do either of the below.

**Option 1**

```
pages/index.js: pass primary key to component1, component2, component3
component1: read data from database with primary key
component2: read data from database with primary key and some additional joins
component3: read data from database with primary key and use only part of the data
```

**Option 2**

```
pages/index.js: read data from database with primary key (and some additional joins)
component1: pass data via props
component2: pass joined data via props
component3: pass part of data via props
```

Which option do you consider more performant to run? Or is there even a better option?

I assume that the first is faster during runtime but incur costs on additional database requests. The second is lighter on the database but not sure what the maximum size of objects is that you can pass via props. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: you would have to do both and measure it to find out.. but I would predict that in 90% of real world scenarios option 2 would be much, MUCH, faster

Comment: Are you trolling? A database hit is a serious bottleneck in any synchronous code flow, right below a network call. Props aren't limited in any way, just like any JavaScript object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option 2 will be much faster. In option 1 you are making lot of request which makes the servers(database) performance low. As you said you are using react js, you can use react-redux. get the data from the database and store it in the redux store. now you can use it any where inside your project.

Answer (score 1):

Measure both and see which one performs better. I would argue that passing props, the second option, is much faster. I'm pretty sure the bottleneck created by several database hits can't possibly be compared to the size of a javascript object.

In short, go for the second option.